# delete all the package imports from the all the .java from the project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, package

I am new to automation scripting, below is a problem I have faced

All the package imports are deleted from every `.java` file in the project in the eclipse including in the framework as well which gives an error while running the application as `mvn` test in the cmd prompt.

is there any way we can delete all the imports(not just the unused package, including the packages used) from all the java source code.

I am using the Maven build tool and Junit, I have deleted the project and rebuild. I am unable to recreate. please suggest

Comment: Do you want to delete all imports or do you want to recreate them?

Comment: Deleting all the imports would break the Java code, so Eclipse does not provide a way to do that.